# JS if condition is executed only if the condition is true on loading of the file

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, frontend

Though there were similar questions answered on this topic,The problem didn't seem to get solved for me,

> My function (go) works only if the size of the window is satisfying the if
> condn. during the loading of the file

I even tried using **resize()** event in jquery <*which didn't work*>

FYI I'm a beginner,Here is my code

**JS**

```
let topbar_children  = $('.topbar').children(); 

var media_width_600px = window.matchMedia("(max-width:600px)").matches;

var media_width_grt_600px = window.matchMedia("(min-width:600px)").matches;




 function go () {
    if (media_width_600px ) {
        var div_left = topbar_children[0];
        $(topbar_children[0]).detach();
        var dropdown_div = document.createElement('div');
        dropdown_div.classList.add('left-side');
        dropdown_div.appendChild(div_left);
        dropdown_div.classList.add('dropdown_content_500px');
        console.log(topbar_children);
        document.body.prepend(dropdown_div);

    } if(media_width_grt_600px ){
       
        dropdown_div.removeChild(div_left);
    }
       
    

 }
 
go();
```

*Also mention a way to refactor my code if possible*

Check this github repo https://github.com/antonrejoe/Oliver_orchard **getting_responsive** branch

Thanks in advance

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"Write a title that **summarizes** the specific problem"_ -> _"In the body of your question, **start by expanding on the summary** you put in the title. Explain how you encountered the problem you're trying to solve, and any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself. The first paragraph in your question is the second thing most readers will see, so make it as engaging and informative as possible."_

Comment: you are calling go() function only one time. that's why your function runs only after reload. If you want to rerun your function on any event, you have to create an event listener like resize, onclick etc. then put your function in that event listner.

Comment: Don't mix `var` and `let`. IMO you should ignore `var` completely and only use `let` and `const`.

Comment: @MirzaUmair bro it is working countless number of times but getting failed unexpectedly ,(and also happens if I try to execute without refreshing) then if I refresh things go well